# Linking from set of iron-pages to sub-pages with a different app-header and back

Tags: polymer

**Here’s a scenario:** 
I have a three page website implementing `<iron-pages>`. Nav is a toolbar with three paper tabs, no drawer. When I click on the tabs, the content of the iron-pages loads below the toolbar. All good.

Now, I have a few child pages that I want to link from the content of one of the three pages. When the page loads, I don’t want it to load below the three tabs but rather be sort of a new page with a different toolbar, with an arrow on the top left to return to the previous view, separate header title, etc.

**A few questions:**

Should these child pages be part of the same `<iron-pages>` list that the three main pages are in? If not, how do you recommend? (When I do, content loads below the toolbar, as expected.)

Should these be an entirely separate page, like a sibling to index.html or in /src, that I link to? If so, is it part of the same app then?

Sorry for the noob questions. Still trying to understand how single page apps are structured, in such scenarios. Eventually I want these pages to be `<animated-pages>` so that I can transition from the main page to the child pages and back. Will save those questions for another time...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to move your nav-bar component to each of your top level pages that need it. You can then move your new "sub-page" so it's a sibling of your other pages.

How users navigate to your different pages does not necessarily need to dictate how you structure the DOM.

#### Answers to your other questions

> Should these child pages be part of the same  list that
>   the three main pages are in? If not, how do you recommend? (When I do,
>   content loads below the toolbar, as expected.)

From what I can tell, no. Keeping all of your pages (even "sub-pages") as siblings will decouple the DOM from the app hierarchy (ie if the hiearchy of your views change, your markup can stay the same).

> Should these be an entirely separate page, like a sibling to
>   index.html or in /src, that I link to? If so, is it part of the same
>   app then?

Polymer lets us build composable building blocks, so I'd recommend having a different custom web component for each of these pages. In my apps, I usually stick all of my web components in the same folder. A sample directory structure might look like this:

```
my-app/
  index.html
  src/
    components/
      nav-bar.html
      my-page1.html
      my-page2.html
      my-page3.html
```

You can then make use of your custom components in index.html